# Firebase Functions Initial Hello World Doesn't Compile in TS

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools, grpc-node

I have an existing webapp project hosted in Firebase, and I want to add cloud functions to it. But when I just functions with the command `firebase init functions` the initial hello-world template it generates doesn't compile in TypeScript because of errors in the gRPC node module.

**My folder structure:**

```
firebase
├── .firebaserc
├── firebase.json
├── webapp     // My web app. Compiles and runs well.
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── src
└── functions  // Only what was autogenerated by firebase-tools.
    ├── .eslintrc.js
    ├── package.json
    ├── tsconfig.json
    ├── tsconfig.dev.json
    └── src
        └── index.ts
```

**What I've Done**

In my `firebase` root folder I ran `firebase init functions` and selected the correct project, to use TypeScript, have the default ESLint definitions, and to install the packages.

I commented out the Hello World function in `functions/src/index.ts`.

I'm using the latest node 16 LTS and firebase-tools version 10.0.1.

**The Error I'm Getting**

When I run `npm run build` in my `functions` folder I get these errors.

```
> build
> tsc

node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/object-stream.d.ts:11:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'IntermediateObjectWritable<T>' incorrectly extends interface 'Writable'.
  The types returned by 'end(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'this'.
      'this' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'void'.

11 export interface IntermediateObjectWritable<T> extends Writable {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/server-call.d.ts:64:5 - error TS2416: Property 'end' in type 'ServerWritableStreamImpl<RequestType, ResponseType>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Writable'.
  Type '(metadata?: any) => void' is not assignable to type '{ (cb?: (() => void) | undefined): this; (chunk: any, cb?: (() => void) | undefined): this; (chunk: any, encoding: BufferEncoding, cb?: (() => void) | undefined): this; }'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'this'.
      'this' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'void'.

64     end(metadata?: any): void;
       ~~~

node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/server-call.d.ts:77:5 - error TS2416: Property 'end' in type 'ServerDuplexStreamImpl<RequestType, ResponseType>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Duplex'.
  Type '(metadata?: any) => void' is not assignable to type '{ (cb?: (() => void) | undefined): this; (chunk: any, cb?: (() => void) | undefined): this; (chunk: any, encoding?: "ascii" | "utf8" | "utf-8" | "utf16le" | "ucs2" | "ucs-2" | "base64" | "base64url" | "latin1" | "binary" | "hex" | undefined, cb?: (() => void) | undefined): this; }'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'this'.
      'this' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'void'.

77     end(metadata?: any): void;
       ~~~


Found 3 errors.
```

**What I've Tried**

- Tried reverting to firebase-tools version 9.23.3 with the latest node 14 LTS. Same error.
- Tried a new firebase project from scratch. Got the same error.
- Tried going back from my M1 Mac to my previous Intel Mac. Also didn't help.

The only thing that works for me is using the JS firebase-functions template instead of the TS one, and it seems like that's what I will proceed with for now. Because that works great right off the bat, and I deployed it without hiccups and it works fine. But I really prefer using TS.

I definitely have a feeling I'm missing something very elementary here. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Update: 06 JAN 2022

A new version of `@grpc/grpc-js` has been released that now fixes this issue with thanks to [@murgatroid99](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159388). Just install v1.4.6 or later and update any dependencies as instructed in the [original issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/2002)'s thread.

```
npm install --save @grpc/grpc-js@^1.4.6
```

---

This is a known compatibility issue between `@types/node` and `@grpc/grpc-js` as discussed in [Issue #2002](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/2002).

Current solution is to downgrade your `@types/node` dependency back a version.

Until it gets patched:

- If you have v14.18.4, go back to v14.18.3.
- If you have v17.0.6, go back to v17.0.5.
- and so on...

You add it to your `package.json` file:

```
"@types/node": "14.18.3"
```

Comment: Amazing! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Didn't work for me, went back to JS over TS

Answer (score 0):

This was a compatibility issue between `@types/node` and `@grpc/grpc-js` which was fixed with the release of version 1.4.6 of `@grpc/grpc-js`. If you update your dependencies to pick up that version, you will not longer have this error.